# In dropwizard, how do I redirect System.out.print messages to a files using yaml file?

Tags: logging, stdout, logback, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard 0.9.2. I want any print statements, in my apps or imported libraries to log into a file.

I tried

https://sysgears.com/articles/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-writing-to-a-log4j-appender/

but couldn't map out_log from its properties file to my yaml file.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code that you tried and all expections/errors. Preferably, try and create a small ode snippet that can run and reproduces your issue

Comment: I have tried the one in link.

Comment: logging:
  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO
  # Logger-specific levels.
  loggers:
    io.dropwizard: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: file
      threshold: WARN
      archive: true
      timeZone: IST
      logFormat: "\"%highlight(%-5level) [%date] [%thread] [%cyan(%logger{0})]: %message%n\""
      currentLogFilename: "/Users/xyz/Documents/file.log"
      maxFileSize: 20KB
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: "/Users/xyz/Documents/file-%i.log.gz"
      archivedFileCount: 5

Comment: `System.setErr(new PrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream(
        Logger.getLogger("outLog"), Level.ERROR)));` didn't do the job to intercept ?

Comment: From the link, can you tell me how exactly do I write in yml file? Where do I write log4j.logger.outLog=error, out_log (define outLog) in yml file?

Comment: If you want to filter `outLog` I update my answer, or you can mix in with other log. Here the interceptor generate error log for logger named `òutLog`

Comment: Please use the edit functionality as comments can not be formatted. The main thing that I can see here is that you need to wire the correct logging stream (as suggested by Orel) manually. Just adding a yaml configuration will not help you. Frankly, this solution should work perfectly fine with any logger (it does not need to be outLog) as any logger will just take your default configuration (e.g. log to the standard file that you always log to). The outLog is only really necessary if you want to split normal logging and print statements to different files

Comment: Sure. Will use edit functionality. This solution didn't work. After I added the statement System.setOut(new PrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream(Logger.getLogger("outLog"), Level.ALL))); , print statements are not coming to console, but its also not going to file I wrote under outLog logger.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand to not print but use logger.

Into the configuration in the logging part
you can define default level, in my example INFO
then you can define some loggers with specifi logger and appenders
Here for com.mystuff packages all level are logged into a file and rotate.

You can also define some global appenders, here one for the console.

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    io.dropwizard: DEBUG
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlets: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.SQL: ALL
    com.mystuff:
        level: ALL,
        additive: false
        appenders:
            - type: file
              archive: true
              timeZone: UTC
              currentLogFilename: /var/log/mine/stuff.log
              archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/log/mine/stuff-%d.log.gz
              archivedFileCount: 50
              logFormat: "%date;%-5level;%message%n"
            - type: console
              logFormat: "%red(CDR) [%magenta(%date)] [%thread] [%cyan(%logger{0})]: %message%n"
  appenders:
    - type: console
      logFormat: "%highlight(%-5level) [%magenta(%date)] [%thread] [%cyan(%logger{0})]: %message%n"
```

For your case, the specific logger is outLog where the interceptor sends ERROR log

```
logging:
    level: ALL
    logger:
      outLog:
        level: ERROR
        additive: false
        appenders:
            - type: file
              archive: true
              timeZone: UTC
              currentLogFilename: /var/log/mine/extra.log
              archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/log/mine/extra-%d.log.gz
              archivedFileCount: 50
              logFormat: "%date;%message%n"
    appenders:
        - type: file
          archive: true
          timeZone: UTC
          currentLogFilename: /var/log/mine/stuff.log
```

Comment: by the sound of OP's question, this is not what he wants. He has libraries that he has no access to that use sys-out statements. He wants to intercept and log these statements.

Comment: Exactly. I have same configs set up. I have successfully logged Error,warning logs to specific files. But in a team if someone keeps sout by mistake, I want it to go to separate file and not affect logs.

Comment: Also, due to sysout commands, the output is going to some tmp file, which is deleted but file desc is holding that file. As output is continuously going to that file, the file size keeps increasing, leading to disk full usage. The main problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: For your space consumption try `cat /dev/null > var/log/myfile`

Comment: yes bt I don't want to do it manually every specific interval. So don't want to solve the problem but avoid having it in first place.

Comment: I tried this, also as I want all sys-outs to log to a file I wrote System.setOut(new PrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream( Logger.getLogger("outLog"), Level.ALL))); But this didn't work. The sys-outs are not coming to console, but it is not even going to the file. I don't know where they are going..!!